# Unit Testing with Kiwi, Core Data and Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm having issues using a 'fake' store for my Unit Tests.
I have installed Kiwi by adding its framework folder to my project and replacing the Xcode's default test cases with Kiwi tests. These all run fine.

Since I'm using Core Data, I need to create a 'fake' store so I'm playing with the real database. I used http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/15/unit-testing-with-core-data/ as my basic guide to do this.

However, since Xcode's default test implementation runs tests after launching the app, my     '[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"Store.sqlite"]' is still fired inside the App Delegate before any of the tests run.

By the time the tests try to use '[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore]', this sqlite store is set up, and so the in-memory store doesn't get set up (AFAIK), since the aforementioned setup stack method checks first to see if a stack already exists, and just returns without executing anything if it does, so I end up with the sqlite database still.

As far as I can tell, this leaves me with the following options:

1. Put some environment variables or flags in for the test cases, and check for these in the app delegate, creating the appropriate store depending on this variable (i.e. tweaking my actual code for the sake of testing - not pretty, nor recommended by any practising TDD/BDDers).
2. Add managed context properties on all my controllers so I can manually specify the store to use (removing a great deal of the niceties of the MagicalRecord singleton access pattern).
3. Play (carefully) with my actual database (I'm not really willing to even contemplate this).

None of these seems to be a particularly good solution, so I'm hoping someone can see a better solution that I've stupidly overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests should not be launching the app delegate. Try setting up your tests so that only the tests setup the in-memory core data store, as suggested in the article you reference.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but this stops me from testing UI. For the moment I'm using some flags to leave the database when testing, but I'm moving across to [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) which will eliminate my need for UI tests, and when I've done this I'll stop it from launching the delegate.